# Highchart doesn't draw from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a table which uses array massive for data, for example

```
$count = array( "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" );
```

and a table

```
<table id="datatable1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Count1
        </th>
        <th>
            Count2
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($count as $count1): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $count1 ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $count1 ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wand to draw a chart by clicking a button

```
<input type="button" id="butt"  value="Click me" onclick="clk()">
```

and function that draws a chart

```
 function clk() {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('datatable1')
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.y +' '+ this.x.toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

ofc I have a div container for chart

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

but after I click on button, there is no chart. There is a chart code in page source code, but this diagram has no content. I think problem is with my table data, which I get from array by foreach, but I need to use this way to get table data. So what should I do to draw a chart?

Comment: Have you checked that the jquery and highcharts libraries are loaded correctly ?

Comment: yes. all works perfectly if i define table data manually

Comment: Try removing the &nbsp; in the second column ? It that doesn't work, post your html